# Sequelize ordering bug in multi join

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have `Users` table, that related to many `Stations` and each user has relation with `Info` table, that contains fields `firstName` and `lastName`. I grab it like this:

```
const joinUserInfo: any = {
  model: userInfoModel,
  where: { deletedAt: null },
  required: true,
};
const joinStations = {
  model: stationModel,
  required: true,
};
const notFormatedItems = await this.userRepository.findAll({
  where: { role: 'user' },
  include: [joinUserInfo, joinStations],
  paranoid: false,
  order,
});
```

Than I have a method to build `order`. It looks like this:

```
private createAdminsListOrdering(query) {
  const validOrderingItems = [];
  if (query.fullName) {
    validOrderingItems.push(['info', 'lastName', query.fullName]);
    validOrderingItems.push(['info', 'firstName', query.fullName]);
  }
  if (query.email) {
    validOrderingItems.push(['email', query.email]);
  }
  if (query.station) {
    validOrderingItems.push(['stations', 'name', query.station]);
  }

  return validOrderingItems.push(['createdAt', 'DESC']);
}
```

In cases with `email` or `stations` all works correct. But with `info` it say that didn't see and info column. When I remove `stations` from join like this:

```
const notFormatedItems = await this.userRepository.findAll({
  where: { role: 'user' },
  include: [joinUserInfo],
  paranoid: false,
  order,
});
```

My ordering by `firstName` and `lastName` working correct. What i do wrong? Thank you.

`Users` related with `Stations` as `many-to-many`:

```
  @BelongsToMany(
    () => stationModel,
    () => userStationModel,
  )
  stations?: stationModel[];
```

Comment: Why are you pushing `fullName` into both `firstName` and `lastName`? That looks like a bug.

Comment: I needed to sort by this two fields and in other request this ordering works correct without any problems. But that request didn't have any 'many to many'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in pagination... I use custom function to create pagination:

```
export const paginatedQuery = ({ page = 0, pageSize = 0 }) => {
  if (!pageSize) {
    return {};
  }
  const limit = pageSize;
  const offset = page * pageSize;

  return { offset, limit };
};
```

And full my request was:

```
const notFormatedItems = await this.userRepository.findAll({
  where: { role: 'user' },
  include: [joinUserInfo, joinStations],
  paranoid: false,
  order,
  ...paginatedQuery(query),
});
```

And, when I debug request with `logging` i notice, that my `Info` table is in subquery. Then I began to googling about subqueries in sequelize and found flag `subQuery`, that force to not use subqueries. After this my request works fine:

```
const notFormatedItems = await this.userRepository.findAll({
  where: { role: 'user' },
  include: [joinUserInfo, joinStations],
  paranoid: false,
  order,
  ...paginatedQuery(query),
  subQuery: false,
});
```

Hope it will helps someone.